# DB2 end of stream prematurely reached while reading inputstream

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, db2

Following code:

```
InputStream imageData=image.getInputStream();
byte[] bytes = ByteStreams.toByteArray(imageData);
pst.setBinaryStream(3, imageData, (int)bytes.length);
```

gives the following error:

> com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][t4][2039][11162][3.57.82] End of stream prematurely reached while reading InputStream, parameter #3.  Remaining data has been padded with 0x0. ERRORCODE=-4225, SQLSTATE=null`

and the DDL which I used to create table is following:

```
CREATE TABLE ARCH_TRANCHE.UPLOAD_DETAIL (
    SEQ_ID VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    FILE_NAME VARCHAR(140) NOT NULL,
    IMAGE_FILE BLOB(1048576),
    CREATED_DATE TIMESTAMP,
    LAST_MODIFIED_DATE TIMESTAMP,
    FILE_SIZE VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (SEQ_ID,FILE_NAME)
);
```

Comment: Please use block indentation rather than backticks for chunks of code - backticks are really for small bits of code inline with other text. Have a look now, and you'll see the question is easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem is that you've already *read* the data by this point in order to obtain `bytes`... so when the driver tries to read from `imageData`, it immediately finds there's no more data to read.

I suggest you just set the stream without a length:

```
pst.setBinaryStream(3, image.getInputStream());
```

If you can't do that (as per comments) you could extract all the data into a byte array as you're already doing, then wrap that in a `ByteArrayInputStream`:

```
InputStream imageData = image.getInputStream();
byte[] bytes = ByteStreams.toByteArray(imageData);
pst.setBinaryStream(3, new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes), bytes.length);
```

Comment: I cannot set the stream without length as it is available with version 4.0 driver and I am using 3.56. I found the solution as               `pst.setBinaryStream(3, imageData, imageData.available());`

Comment: @AmitKumarPandit: Using `available()` is a *really* bad idea. That only says how much data is available right now. It may well not reflect the total size of data. I'll present another option.

Comment: Java doc of available () method says like that i dont thik it can be use .
 /**
     * Returns 0 after EOF has reached for the current entry data,
     * otherwise always return 1.
     * <p>
     * Programs should not count on this method to return the actual number
     
     */